# Particles' Wave Function Capability

Tags: wavefunction

Do all particles have the ability to have a wave state even if they are a part of objects larger than those seen tested in the double slit experiment?

Do all particles have the ability to have a wave state even if they are not given energy by being fired across space as seen in the double slit experiment?

Is there any way to know these things?

Thanks

Comment: Try to make your question a bit clearer. Do you mean to ask: does every particle of a macroscopic object has their own individual wavefunction?

Answer (score 0):

If they are moving at great speed and have very tiny mass yes they have an observable wavefunction.By extending the properties of quantun mechanics to the macroscopic world , all objects have wave functions .Those wavefunctions are just to small to influence the object (Planck Scale).Big objects dont have wave properties but tiny particles with tiny mass moving at great speeds do have a wave nature.